# Debug receiving intents

Tags: tasker

I have a Mi Band smart watch and I'm using the [Notify for Mi Band](https://www.mibandnotify.com/) app that adds a lot of great extra functionality.

One thing that I haven't been able to get working is triggering Tasker intents when I press buttons on the watch. I can confirm that the button presses are being detected (the app shows a message for debugging purposes).

There is a setting that should cause the app to fire a Tasker intent on button press. I've enabled this setting and followed [their documentation on receiving this intents](https://www.mibandnotify.com/help/miband2_button_tasker.php), but the task is never called. Is there any way I can see all the intents Tasker is receiving for debugging purposes?

Comment: Are you interested in this: https://tasker.joaoapps.com/userguide/en/activity_runlog.html ?

Comment: @Firelord Unfortunately that doesn't help since my task doesn't run. I want to see what intents are received so I can check that I have the intent names correct.